# How to select the data ordered by the last reply time desc?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select data (message.subject, message.id, message.date from message, reply_message) from 2 tables, and want to make it using their time to order

table 1: message

| id | subject | content | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello World | Just try | 16:01:48 |
| 2 | What is your favorite food? | orange | 16:03:32 |
| 3 | 1+1=? | what is the answer for it? | 16:07:59 |
| 4 | Want to buy a computer | Any recommend? | 16:11:10 |

table 2: reply_message

| id | content | date | reply_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 16:08:14 | 2 |
| 2 | watermelon | 16:08:23 | 2 |
| 3 | bye | 16:08:45 | 1 |
| 4 | banana | 16:11:35 | 2 |

message.id is reply_message.reply_id

I want to see the order is

| id | subject | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | What is your favorite food? | 16:03:32 |
| 4 | Want to buy a computer | 16:11:10 |
| 1 | Hello World | 16:01:48 |
| 3 | 1+1=? | 16:07:59 |

I try the below command, but cannot get my expected result

```
select distinct message.subject, message.id, message.date
from message, reply_message
order by reply_message.date desc
```

It just give me the below result. What is wrong of my command? Thanks

| id | subject | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello World | 16:01:48 |
| 2 | What is your favorite food? | 16:03:32 |
| 3 | 1+1=? | 16:07:59 |
| 4 | Want to buy a computer | 16:11:10 |

Sorry for my poor English and thank you in advance for your concerns and help

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scalar subquery to compute the last reply date/time. Then, sorting is easy. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select m.*, (
      select max(date) from reply_message r where r.reply_id = m.id
    ) as rt
  from message m
) x
order by rt desc, date
-- order by coalesce(rt, date) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to make it sort by time (if no reply in the message, then use the message posted time. If there is reply in the message, then use the reply time)? Thanks

Comment: @lead9upper Yes, just change the last line to specify the ordering criteria. You can sort by two columns (as shown) or using `COALESCE()`.